# Is there an endpoint for 'lineups'?

Tags: nba-api

I have searched through the questions and the documentation but I can't find any endpoint that returns the data found at:

https://www.nba.com/stats/lineups/traditional

I found a couple of endpoints for 'PlayerDashLineups' and 'TeamDashLineups' but those don't have the fields that I'm looking for with the 'lineups' endpoint.

Is there an endpoint for 'lineups' that maybe isn't in the documentation?